# Внедрение своих скриптов к другим сайтам. Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Меня интересует, могу ли я написать свой небольшой скрипт(JS, JQuery), например для смены цвета фона и внедрить (подключить) к другому сайту.

Например есть сайт `http://example.com/` цвет фона красный, могу ли я как-то подключить скрипт для смены цвета на зеленый, допустим. С чего начать поиски в данном направлении?

Comment: Если вы сможете модифицировать разметку этого сайта, вставив туда тег `script`, то вы сможете выполнить необходимые вам изменения.

Comment: Вам надо ваш скрипт сделать расширением браузера. В настройках любого расширения указывается на каких сайтах они должны срабатывать, а сами расширения пишутся обычно именно на JS

Comment: Если есть доступ ко всем сайтам, которым вы хотите внедрять скрипты, то есть 2 варианта: либо вы строите API, либо просто подключаете скрипты и указываете ссылки на на ваши скрипты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если речь идёт лишь о смене внешнего вида страницы, то можете использовать **пользовательские стили** в браузере.

Другой вариант заключается в том, чтобы написать **расширения для браузера**, которое будет работать с любой заданной страницей на своих условиях: JS, jQuery, CSS и т.п.

Comment: Я только что нашел такую вещь, как userscripts. Двигаюсь в сторону рассширений